# Search for a field that contains a string Access 07

Tags: sql, ms-access

Earlier in the day I figured out the following query.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Visits.KHA_ID, Visits.totalCharges
    FROM (Visits INNER JOIN (ICDTable INNER JOIN ICDVisitsJxn ON ICDTable.ICD9ID = ICDVisitsJxn.ICD_IDFK) ON Visits.ID = ICDVisitsJxn.VisitsIDFK) 
INNER JOIN (ICDTable AS ICDTable_1 
INNER JOIN ICDVisitsJxn AS ICDVisitsJxn_1 ON ICDTable_1.ICD9ID = ICDVisitsJxn_1.ICD_IDFK) ON Visits.ID = ICDVisitsJxn_1.VisitsIDFK
    WHERE (((ICDTable.Description) 
Like "*[enter term]*") AND ((ICDTable_1.Description) Like "*[enter another term]*"));
```

This works the way I want it to.  I would prefer, however, if instead of having to type the exact text in the corresponding field that the user could search for a string of text.  This would be akin to the Like *word here* construct Access uses.  I've always hardcoded the substrings.  Anyone know how to do this programatically.

Comment: the italics word here should be surrounded by asterisks.

Comment: The exception to the rule for reserved words is where the word is prefixed with the table name or an alias, in that case, the square brackets are not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running this in Access, just add * :

```
WHERE (((ICDTable.Description) Like "*" & [enter term]  & "*") 
AND ((ICDTable_1.Description) Like "*" & [enter another term] & "*"));
```

You can refer to a control on a form:

```
WHERE (((ICDTable.Description) Like "*" & Forms!MyForm!FirstTerm  & "*") 
AND ((ICDTable_1.Description) Like "*" & Forms!MyForm!SecondTerm & "*"));
```

Comment: I tried that and it returned all records.  lemme see if i did something wrong.

Comment: If you do not enter a term, it will return all records, because you have `WHERE Something Like *`

Answer (score 2):

in addition to Remou's answer, this link may also be useful to you:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tips-for-using-wildcard-characters-in-microsoft-access-criteria-expressions/6154704